# My offer letter entitled me to 2.5% interest in the company after 2 years. Its been 2 years and nothing

Tags: equity

My offer letter states I am entitled to the 2.5% interest in the company after completing 2 years. I've done that and so far just getting the brush off. What can  I do? or should do?

Comment: What do you mean by 'brush off'? "Don't bother me now?" "You're not going to get that"? "We didn't really mean that?" Who exactly have you talked to?

Comment: Well either let it go, or fight for it.  If you want to fight for it you really need a lawyer...

Comment: Brush off as in "its not a good time". This was the response from the owner.

Comment: If it was in your legal contract they *should* comply to it.. you are in your right to ask for that.

Comment: Your next question should be "when is a good time?". Make an appointment to come and talk, at a time convenient to them (but not very far in the future).

Comment: tried that, now there are legal investigations going on so no one is talking.

Comment: @queenezgurl - You may not want that 2.5% interest... depending on how the company is organized you could end up on the hook for 2.5% of the debt if they screwed something up.

Comment: Could you add those details and background to your question so other users can understand better? In what way are they investigating (who also?)

Comment: I was told to present a Demand to Perform to them. Can they retaliate for that and fire me?

Comment: @queenezgurl this smells weird.. I suggest you take a **good** look at your contract

Comment: Who were you told this by?

Comment: Some type of fraud was committed, a raid was done at the corporate office. Now they are trying to pick up the pieces. It seems like they are trying to redirect, sale or shut down.

Comment: The offer letter is very clear. No stipulations. It is simply worded "after two years of employment I am entitled to 2.5% in the company".

Comment: In any case, I'd start looking for a new job. Fraud investigation, *and* failure to pay out contract, *and* you possibly suing the company all amounts to you wanting to work somewhere else.

Comment: @queenezgurl, under no circumstances do you want 2.5% of that company.  Get out now.

Comment: Lesson 1, don't trust bonuses and future promises.

Comment: BTW, where are you located?  In many places offer letters are just fluff with no enforceability.

Answer (score 6):

You can choose to either let it go and hope they eventually make good on their promise, or you can fight for it.

If you want to fight for it you should really consult a lawyer.  They can tell you if you have any grounds to stand on.  But that is not something we are going to be able to help you with here probably.

If you choose to fight for it realize you are probably not going to make friends with the company exec and may come to regret fighting for that interest.  But only you can make that choice.